# rearrange array elements

Tags: javascript

In an array T we have values [e,t,m,a]. How to reorder this array in a single loop in the aim to get [t,e,a,m]?

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Do you mean you want to sort it? Or do you mean you want to have it in an arbitrary order? Please add more context

Answer (score 3):

```
var T = ['e','t','m','a']
var ordered = order(T)
function order(T){
  return [T[1],T[0],T[3],T[2]]
}
```

... or ...

```
T.concat(T.splice(0,2)).reverse()
```

Answer (score 2):

I think even though it's phrased poorly and doesn't seem to make sense why you'd need to do this, if I'm deciphering your question correctly this is what you're trying to do:

```
var goal = ['a','t','o','m','i','c'],
    scramble = ['c', 't', 'm', 'a', 'o', 'i'],
    index,
    holder;

for (var i = 0, gl = goal.length; i < gl; i++) {
    index = scramble.indexOf(goal[i]);
    holder = scramble.splice(index, 1)[0];
    scramble.splice(i, 0, holder);
}

alert(scramble); // -> a,t,o,m,i,c
```